# Text animation has stopped working - html isn't finding my CSS3 anymore

Tags: html, wordpress, css, animation

So I'm using a CSS3 animation on a WP theme I'm trying to build as a student project, half an hour ago it was working fine. I added in the 3 text / images boxes at the bottom, checked back and now it has stopped working!

I've been trying to amend this for ages now and I'm too scared to go any further in case I break more stuff!

The webpage is http://jacobstone.co.uk/leggera2/
JS Fiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/2hjz8/

So my html is

```
<div class="hero-unit">
<div id="logo-title">Leggera</div>
<div id="tagline">Responsive</div>
<div class="Iam">
<p>This is</p>
<b>
  <div class="innerIam">
    leggera 
    a theme in progress<br />
    built on bootstrap<br />
    how I learn stuff<br />
    how we do it
  </div>
</b>
</div>
```

& The CSS is:

```
/* fancy scroll title */
div .Iam {
    position: relative;
    width: 625px;
    padding-left: 1%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    right: 45px;
    top: -80px;

}

.Iam {
  padding: 2em 5em;
  font: normal 40px/50px Montserrat, sans-serif;
  color: #999;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 1px rgba(38, 38, 38, 1);
}
.Iam p {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 0.3em;
}
.Iam b {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}
.Iam .innerIam {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #e74c3c;
  position: relative;
  white-space: nowrap;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

/*animation*/
-webkit-animation:move 5s;
   -moz-animation:move 5s;
    -ms-animation:move 5s;
     -o-animation:move 5s;
        animation:move 5s;
/*animation-iteration-count*/
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
     -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
        animation-iteration-count:infinite;
/*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
   -moz-animation-delay:1s;
    -ms-animation-delay:1s;
     -o-animation-delay:1s;
        animation-delay:1s;
}
@keyframes move{
    0%  { top: 0px; }
    20% { top: -50px; }
    40% { top: -100px; }
    60% { top: -150px; }
    80% { top: -200px; }
}

@-webkit-keyframes move {
    0%  { top: 0px; }
    20% { top: -50px; }
    40% { top: -100px; }
    60% { top: -150px; }
    80% { top: -200px; }
}
@-moz-keyframes move {
    0%  { top: 0px; }
    20% { top: -50px; }
    40% { top: -100px; }
    60% { top: -150px; }
    80% { top: -200px; }
}
@-o-keyframes move {
    0%  { top: 0px; }
    20% { top: -50px; }
    40% { top: -100px; }
    60% { top: -150px; }
    80% { top: -200px; }
}
@keyframes move {
    0%  { top: 0px; }
    20% { top: -50px; }
    40% { top: -100px; }
    60% { top: -150px; }
    80% { top: -200px; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Can you post a JSFiddle link instead of a link to your website please?

Comment: I'm not sure what part is meant to be broken

Comment: Oops sorry, the bit that says 'Leggera' should be animated and the text change. Like so - http://codepen.io/JacobStone420/pen/dyEvl

Comment: Will post JSFiddle in one sec

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2hjz8/ Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the closing bracket (`}`) after `left: 0;` in `.Iam .innerIam` is the problem.
If you remove it the animation is working again.

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hjz8/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't include your animation in the correponding class.

```
.Iam .innerIam {
display: inline-block;
color: #e74c3c;
position: relative;
white-space: nowrap;
top: 0;
left: 0;


/*animation*/
-webkit-animation:move 5s;
-moz-animation:move 5s;
 -ms-animation:move 5s;
 -o-animation:move 5s;
    animation:move 5s;
/*animation-iteration-count*/
-webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
-ms-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 -o-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    animation-iteration-count:infinite;
 /*animation-delay*/
-webkit-animation-delay:1s;
-moz-animation-delay:1s;
-ms-animation-delay:1s;
 -o-animation-delay:1s;
    animation-delay:1s;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hjz8/2/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I don't have enough rep to Vote Up your answers, sorry!!

Comment: Well, when you do one day you can come back and do so.. ;) Glad we could help!